# Client getting 'Bad Request' response from server

Tags: node.js, sockets, traefik

I'm using nodejs net library.
Locally everything works fine, I can connect to server with client, send data to server and I'm getting response.

But once deployed on server (with traefik), when I run client-app.js I keep getting:

```
Connected
Received: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Connection: close

400 Bad Request
Connection closed
```

Traefik is configured to redirect every request that comes to "my-address.com" to 1337 port on docker container (in which runs server-app.js).

Here's my code:

server-app.js:

```
const net = require('net');

const PORT = 1337;
const HOST = '0.0.0.0';

var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
    socket.write('Echo server\r\n');
    //socket.pipe(socket);

    socket.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log('DATA RECEIVED')
        socket.write('GOT DATA', data)

    });

});

server.on('connection', (socket)=> {
    console.log('Connection from: ', socket.remoteAddress)
});

server.listen(PORT, HOST, () => {
    console.log(`SERVER IS UP. PORT ${PORT}`)
})
```

client-app.js:

```
const net = require('net');


const PORT = 443;
const HOST = 'my-addres.com';

var client = new net.Socket();
console.dir(client.connect)
client.connect({port: PORT, host: HOST}, function() {
    console.log('Connected');
    client.write('Hello, server! Love, Client.\n');
    var counter = 1;

    setInterval(()=>{client.write(`Data nr ${counter}\n`); counter += 1}, 1000)
});

client.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('Received: ' + data);
    //client.destroy(); // kill client after server's response
});

client.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Connection closed');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your client and server don't speak the HTTP protocol but do their own application protocol on top of TCP. But it looks like you've configured Traefik to be a HTTP router since what you receive is a HTTP response. Since you don't use HTTP you should not use a HTTP but a [TCP router](https://docs.traefik.io/routing/routers/#configuring-tcp-routers) instead.